# How do I get new tab/window behavior to be the same across multiple browsers?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cross-browser

I'm running Selenium tests using web driver.

When I try to open a new tab or a new window in the browser, the behavior is different depending on which browser I'm testing against.

Here's the method I'm using. The code is the same for a new tab instead of a new window, just replace the key pressed with "t" instead of "n".

```
protected void logOutInAnotherTab() {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "n");
    List<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    PageObject.logout(driver);
    PageUtil.waitForPageLoad(driver, 3);
    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
}
```

It is supposed to open a new tab/window, switch to it, navigate to the logout url (which ends the user's session), then close the tab/window (switching to the original tab/window), allowing the test case to proceed with the user's session ended.

If I do it for tabs, both Firefox and IE return only the original tab when I call `driver.getWindowHandles()`, which results in an index out of bounds on the next line. In other words, the new tab isn't recognized by the webdriver, so switching to it fails.

If I do it for windows, I have the same problem, but only IE suffers from it; the Firefox web driver gets both windows just fine. Also, IE loads the same page as the original window, instead of a start page or the home page, which poses additional problems.

In all cases I can get Chrome to behave the way I expect it to.

How can I get all three of these desktop browsers (IE, Firefox, and Chrome) to behave the same when I'm dealing with multiple tabs or windows?

Or, more to my need, how can I open a new tab/window in all three browsers and switch to that tab/window successfully, then later close the tab/window and switch back to the original one successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I am switching tabs based on tab names. Following are my code, hope it make sense.

```
public void SwitchTo(String tabName) {

        String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> set = driver.getWindowHandles();

        for (String s : set) {

            if (currentHandle.equals(s)) {
                continue;
            }

            driver.switchTo().window(s);

            if (driver.getTitle().equals(tabName)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: i just provided my local method without driver initialization, don't figure out that "What is the driver?".

> If I do it for tabs, both Firefox and IE return only the original tab when I call driver.getWindowHandles()

As I can see if `getWindowHandles` only returns original tab, this maybe due to the versions stuff. See

[Firefox does not list tabs in getAllWindowHandles](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1614)

Comment: This does not solve my problem. For IE and Firefox, `driver.getWindowHandles()` returns a Set with only 1 item in it; the original tab/window. Iterating through that Set won't magically add the other tab/window.